# Why can I delete a variable declared a = 1 and not one declared var b = 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose we are in the global scope:

When I declare a variable in JS:

```
a = 1
```

which I know is not the proper way (but it is not the question).
I can use:

```
delete a (> returns true)
```

But when I declare:

```
var b = 1
```

I can't use:

```
delete b (> returns false)
```

Can anyone explain that behaviour?

Comment: What's the full code? One is a global variable (without var) while the other is local to the function it is declared in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `delete` is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

`a` becomes/is ultimately interpreted as `window.a`, while `b` clearly refers to a *local variable*.

Comment: That fact that you can access `b` through `window.b` too also adds to the confusion...

Comment: Yeah, let's not get into that, or we'll all need a stiff drink... ;)